# What is the right A/C contactor part that I need?

Tags: electrical, hvac, air-conditioning

I need to replace my A/C contactor, but I'm not sure what exact model I need for the new part. I took two photos showing the Brand and model number of it but when I search it on Amazon, I cant seem to find the exact one. I was wondering if I can use different brands instead of the one I have put in right now, I'm just not sure. Can someone maybe give me a link to a one which is compatible with this model or explain what other ones I can use.

Brand: Honeywell

Model: R8243A 1031

24V 50/60HZ

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I searched R8243 and came up with a Honeywell cross R4243b1012.

Part numbers change all the time but this should be a compatible part 24v coil and a double pole contact set without knowing your compressor size it would be hard to guess at the right size because Honeywell did not provide the specs for the original.

It’s not a big deal as long as the control voltage 24v is the same   It’s a double pole motor contactor the last part would be the HP rating.  Well and it fits. It won’t hurt to get a larger one as long as it fits. I put larger ones in all the time the contacts actually last longer.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the bottom of the tag where it shows the amp rating of the contactor. Get a new one rated the same size or slightly larger with the same number of switched contacts and a 24 volt coil.